# calling paintComponent() from another class - NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

Hi I'm currently developing a Super Hexagon Clone, but unfortunately am very bad at java. I do understand it generally, but I neither was I ever taught most specifics nor did I ever have the time to properly get into programming in general....

The first programm, where the actual game is just running, tells the class "Wall" what kind of Wall to spawn thus what information to give to the programm where everything is drawn.

This is Frame.java:

```
package madhex;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Area;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Frame2 extends JFrame{
    public Screen screen;

    int w = 1280, h = 800, r= 50;
    int playery[] = {(h/2)+r+20, ((h/2)+r+20)-8, ((h/2)+r+20)-8};
    int playerx[] = {w/2, (w/2)-8, (w/2)+8};


    public Frame2()
        {
            super("Hexagon");
            screen = new Screen();
            screen.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
            add(screen);
            addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
        }




    public void repaintScreen(){
        screen.repaint();
    }

    public class Screen extends JLabel
    {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics g2 = g;
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

        //generelle Drehung
        at.setToRotation(dreiecktest.getRotation(), w/2, h/2);
        ((Graphics2D) g2).setTransform(at);

        //Hexagon
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.drawPolygon(hexagonx, hexagony, 6);

        //A
        g2.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g2.fillPolygon(A1x, A1y, 4);
        g2.fillPolygon(A2x, A2y, 4);
        g2.fillPolygon(A3x, A3y, 4);

        //B
        g2.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g2.fillPolygon(B1x, B1y, 4);
        g2.fillPolygon(B2x, B2y, 4);
        g2.fillPolygon(B3x, B3y, 4);

        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fillPolygon(testx, testy, 12);

        //Player
        at.setToRotation(dreiecktest.getGrad()+dreiecktest.getRotation(), w/2, h/2);
        System.out.println(getPlayerRotation());
        System.out.println(getPlayerSector());
        ((Graphics2D) g2).setTransform(at);

        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fillPolygon(playerx, playery, 3);



        }

        public void draw(Graphics g, int Ax[],int Ay[])
        {
            Graphics g3 = (Graphics)g;
            super.paintComponent(g3);

            g3.fillPolygon(Ax, Ay, 12);
        }

    }

}
```

The Method draw(Graphics g, int ArrayForXcoordinates, int ArrayForYcoordinates) is supposed to get the array from Wall.java:

```
public class Wall
{
Frame2 f = new Frame2();
int openSector= 0;
int d = 50;
int w=1280, h =800, r=50;
Graphics g = f.screen.getGraphics();

Wall (int openSector) {
    this.openSector = openSector;

}

public void display() 
{
    if (openSector == 1)
    {
        int Ax [] = {_values}
        int Ay [] = {_values}

        f.screen.draw(g, Ax, Ay);

    }
    if (openSector== 2)
    {

            //I left out the arrays, because they were just taking up too much space        

        f.screen.draw(g, Ax, Ay);
    }


    f.screen.draw(g, Ax, Ay);
}

public void tick () 
{
    d--;
    this.display();
}
}
```

But I get a NullPointerException at f.screen.draw(g, Ax, Ay), at super.paintComponent(g3); in the method draw() and at the point in the actual runtime-programm, where the Method tick() from Wall is run.

I'm all out of help and although I will understand, if someone explains it to me, I have completely given up on finding it out myself by just googling my problems.....

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: please post the stack trace of the NPE

Comment: `Graphics g = f.screen.getGraphics();` is plainly wrong. It is not allowed to fetch the graphics object by calling `getGraphics` (and it is even less allowed to store it and use it later). All the painting has to be done from the scope of the `paintComponent` method, using exactly the `Graphics` that you have received there as an argument. You can imagine the `Graphics` as only being "valid" for this period of time. (Apart from that: Creating a new `Frame` instance in the `Wall` does probably not make sense anyhow)

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I got the getGraphics() from a friend, who was also supposed to help me with this "calling paint from another class"-problem. But how would I actually do all the painting from the main paintComponent? this has been my problem in the first place. I don't know how to get the coordinates of my level elements into that main painComponent method.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.JComponent.getComponentGraphics(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
 at madhex.Frame2$Screen.draw(Frame2.java:143)
 at madhex.Wall.display(Wall.java:49)
 at madhex.Wall.tick(Wall.java:55)
 at madhex.dreiecktest.main(dreiecktest.java:21)

the first linked error is at super.PaintComponent(g3);
2. f.screen.draw(g, Ax, Ay)
3. at this.display()
4. where the method tick() is called from the main programm